# How to style a dynamically created div using JQuery in this function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

I have a problem with this function:

```
$("#contentdiv").click(function() {
    $(this).append("<div class='editable'>For some reason this div cannot be colored</div>");
})

var $currentInput = null;
$("#background_color_button").live("click", function() {
    $currentInput = null;
    if ($currentInput == null) {
        $currentInput = $(this).prev();
        $("label").html($currentInput.attr("id"));
    }
});
var editid;
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($currentInput == null)
        return;      
    var css = GetCssProperties();    
    $(this).css(css);
    $("label").html("");
});

function GetCssProperties() {
    if ($currentInput == null) return null;

    var value = $currentInput.val();
    if ($currentInput.attr("id") == "background-color") {
        return {
        "background-color": value
        }
    }
}
```

**It allows you to change the background color of a div with the class "Editable"**

First you click on a div with the ID "#background_color_button" and it will retrieve the value of the text input above it, and then you click on the div (With class="editable") that you want the style to be applied to.

My problem is here:

```
$("#contentdiv").click(function() {
    $(this).append("<div class='editable'>For some reason this div cannot be colored</div>");
})
```

This function creates a div with class="editable" inside of the div with ID="contentdiv".

However, although it has the class="editable", clicking on the div with ID="background_color_button" and then on the dynamically created div will not cause the style to change like the divs which are NOT dynamically loaded using jQuery.

I know that you can use:

```
.delegate('.editable', 'click', function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

**or**

```
$(".editable").live("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

To accomplish this, but when I try to put the line:

```
.delegate('.editable', 'click', function() {
```

**or**

```
$(".editable").live("click", function() {
```

In place of:

```
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
```

The function no longer works.

Thank you very much in advance,

Taylor

Here is a JSfiddle doc with the project:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/gJLSd/1/

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MTsk3/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are appending within the #contentdiv div and the events are not bubbling down.

So if you change the html from this:

```
<div id="contentdiv">Click here to make a div</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="contentdiv"><span id='clicker'>Click here to make a div</span></div>
```

and then the js from:

```
$("#contentdiv").click(function() {
    $(this).append("<div class='editable'>For some reason this div cannot be colored</div>");
}) 

...
...

$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
     //blah blah blah
});
```

to this:

```
$("#clicker").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append("<div class='editable'>For some reason this div cannot be colored</div>");
})

...
...

$("div.editable").live("click",function(e) {
     //blah blah blah
});
```

Everything works!

Comment: Just remember to add the div: <div class='editable'>For some reason this div cannot be colored</div>

I see how the events were not bubbling down now. I made the fixes, and it works great!